# Looking for protractor resources, wanting to get into this automation tool

Tags: automated-testing, protractor

A lot of surrounding companies are adopting a testing framework called **Protractor**, I am wondering if anyone has any advice on where to get started with this automation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list of useful resources:

- [Official Quick Start guide](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial)
- [Official Docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/docs)
- [Getting starting guide](http://www.kramnameloc.com/getting-started-with-protractor) by Mark Colevan
- [Practical guide, with example application](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/practical-protractor.html)
- [Some advanced techniques](http://product.moveline.com/testing-angular-apps-end-to-end-with-protractor.html)
- [Video lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idb6hOxlyb8) by Jim Lavin

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend knowing WebDriver fairly well and the basics of the template side of AngularJS before learning Protractor. I think a really good course for learning protractor is the *Udemy Protractor: End to End testing Framework for AngularJS apps*. 
As stated in a previous answer the javascript syntax is different from the Java, C# or Ruby implementations of WebDriver but you get used to it pretty quickly and you don't necessarily need to know how a javascript promise works to use it.

Protractor Basics: https://www.udemy.com/angularjs-protractor-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I've heard from co-workers JavaScript isn't the easiest language to use with Web Driver and protractor is based on [Web Driver](http://testautomation.applitools.com/post/94994807787/protractor-vs-selenium-which-is-easier). Something about all the asynchronous calls. You might try web driver with Ruby. Sauce Labs has a Bootcamp available for [free](http://info.saucelabs.com/SeleniumBootcampLP.html?utm_source=sqe&utm_medium=em&utm_campaign=sebootcamp).

Comment: The advantage of Protractor over bare Web Driver is it supports better testing Web applications with UI implemented in angular.js.